# Telegram bot sending text from image back to user

Tags: python, telegram-bot

When using a photo from a computer, there are no errors, when trying to use a photo sent in a telegram, the following exception is displayed. Here is the full code of the bot, I have suspicions that everything is due to the incorrect indication of the variable`message.photo[0].file_id`but on the Internet I did not find the exact path by which you can refer to the sent photo. I'm new to telegram bots, so I will ask you for specifics and the most simple, if possible, explanation. I will be glad to any criticism.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)


@bot.message_handler(content_types= ["photo"])

def answer_to_photo(message):

    image = message.photo[0].file_id
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\OCR\tesseract.exe'

    preprocess = "thresh"

    image = cv2.imread(image)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    if preprocess == "tresh":
        gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    elif preprocess == "blur":
        gray = cv2.median.Blur(gray, 3)

    filename = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
    cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
    os.remove(filename)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
```

Thrown exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "shablon.py", line 58, in <module>
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
 packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 427, in polling
self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 451, in __threaded_polling
self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\telebot\util.py", line 111, in raise_exceptions
six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
raise value
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
task(*args, **kwargs)
 File "shablon.py", line 25, in answer_to_photo
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was that the photos sent by the user must first be downloaded to the computer and after all the processing and selection of the text, delete this photo so as not to take up free space